# Pandas dataframe from generator where each line is a tab-separated row

Tags: python, pandas, generator

I am trying parse a generator to the dataframe constructor, pd.Dataframe `testdf = pd.DataFrame(test)`.  I am unable to specify that each line is tab-delimited. The result is that I end up with a single column dataframe where each row is the entire row of values separated with `'\t'`.

I've tried a couple of other ways:

```
    pd.read_csv(test)  
    pandas.io.parsers.read_table(test, sep='\t')
```

but neither of these work of them work because they do not take the input type generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too familiar with generators. Can you throw them into a list comprehension? If so, how about

```
pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in test])
```

Comment: Great; cuts out a line and feels more pythonic than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found would be to use a split function on the one column to break it up:

```
    testdf_parsed = pd.DataFrame(testdf.row.str.split('\t').tolist(), )
```

...and that did work for me, but maybe there is a more elegant and simple solution exist that leverages the core capabilities of Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You might try implementing a file-like object that wraps your generator, then feeding that to read_table.